# Show that for a smooth function f there exists a ball $B_r(x) := \{y:\|y-x\| < r\}$ such that $\nabla ^\top f(y) B \nabla f(x) >0$ where $B\succ 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

I came across a statement in a proof that says:

If $f$ is a smooth function then $\exists B_r(x):\{y:\|y-x\|<r\}$ such that

$$\nabla^\top f(y) B \nabla f(x) >0$$

where $$B \succ 0 $$

I'm not sure where the claim came from if anyone can provide a useful reference to see that with a proof or an explaining example it would be great.

P.S: I tried googling the statement in many ways and couldn't find what I want.

Comment: Is $B$ a fixed matrix? Is it given or can we choose it? Also you want to exclude constant functions.

Comment: Yep its a fixed real symmetric positive definite matrix

Answer (score 1):

As we are in finite dimensions, we have $B\geq c>0$ (take the lowest eigenvalue of $B$). Now if $f$ is not constant, there exists a point $x$ such that $\Vert \nabla f(x)\Vert \neq 0$. For such an $x$ we have
$$\langle \nabla f(x), B \nabla f(x)\rangle \geq c \Vert \nabla f(x)\Vert^2>0.$$
Now we can use that $g(y):=\langle \nabla f(y), B \nabla f(x)\rangle$ is continuous to obtain the desired ball.